# Parse javascript array into the appropriate input fields with the same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Actually I'm working on a function that compares two dates (one date I get from my hidden input, another date - current datetime).
I wrote a function in JS which works perfect:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("getTime");

        var names = [];
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            names = elements[i].value;
            var dece = moment(names).format();
            var cureTime = moment().format();
            seco=moment().diff(dece, 'seconds');
            if ((Math.floor(seco / 60)) >= 1 && (Math.floor(seco / 60))<60) {
                console.log(Math.floor(seco / 60) + " minutes");
                document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = Math.floor(seco / 60) + " minutes ago";
            }else if(((Math.floor(seco / 3600)) >= 1) && ((Math.floor(seco / 3600))<24))
            {
                console.log(Math.floor(seco / 3600) + " hours");
                document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = Math.floor(seco / 3600) + " hours ago";
            }else if (((Math.floor(seco / 86400)) >= 1) && ((Math.floor(seco / 86400)) <30))
            {
                console.log(Math.floor(seco / 86400) + " days");
                document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = Math.floor(seco / 86400) + " days ago";
            }else if (((Math.floor(seco / 2592000)) > 1) && ((Math.floor(seco / 2592000)) <= 12))
            {
                console.log(Math.floor(seco / 2592000) + " months");
                document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = Math.floor(seco / 2592000) + " months ago";
            }else if((Math.floor(seco / 31536000)) > 1)
            {
                console.log(Math.floor(seco / 31536000) + " years");
                document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML = Math.floor(seco / 31536000) + " years ago";
            }
        }
```

As a result all of those console.logs (in each if statement) return me the right difference in dates.
But now I can't understand how can I parse all of these differences into the appropriate span fields with the same class name. My HTML looks like this:

```
@foreach($repoData as $kek)
     <span class="time" id="openedOn"></span>
    <input type="hidden" class="getTime" id="time" value='{!! $kek->created_at !!}'>
@endforeach
```

To be clear this FOREACH generates me several dates that are stored in the hidden input. Then I get values from this hidden input and pass them to my function in JS.
So I can't understand how should I parse elements from my JS function to that span with class name - "time".
Please help.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an HTML Collection, not a single element....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: its `getElements`(plural), it returns an array. You need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Wow. Thank you @NikhilNanjappa, I rewrote my code with a document.getElementsByClassName("time")[i].innerHTML and it works now. Good job!

Comment: Please post your answer @NikhilNanjappa, maybe it would be helful for someone in the future.

Comment: Don't use `[0]` inside the loop, you can simply make use of the counter(`i`).

Comment: You already figured that out :) I will post an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` functions returns an array(Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) and hence you need to use array notation to access its elements

```
document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML
```

In your case, since your accessing the elements within a loop you should simply make use of the counter(`i`).

```
document.getElementsByClassName("time")[i].innerHTML
```

Replace the above to all the conditions for it to work.